# Custom subview gives memory leak when analyzed

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create my own custom subview for an app.  The view is a subclass of UIView and contains a couple of UIButtons and a UITextField.  The code actually builds and runs without problems, but when I do an "Analyze" of the code it gives me 4 potential memory leaks.  I will be including this subview in a larger project so I want to nip any errors here before adding it to the bigger project.  Here's the code where one of the leaks occurs:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.nameView.delegate = self;
    [self.nameView.newName resignFirstResponder];   // this is line 60
    [self.nameView setHidden:YES];
    [self.nameView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The error it gives me is:"Potential leak of an object created on line 60"
Then if I click on that error is says: "Object allocated on line 60 is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1, object leaked"
Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.
Gil

CocoaFu, thanks for the help - I am new to the site and I will try to give the proper feedback.  As far as this problem goes I should have included a bit more information.
nameView is the name of my custom view
newName is the name of a UITextField in the view. 
I will try then suggestions here and let you know if they work.  Thanks again.  This is a great site!

Comment: Is nameView your custom UIView with the viewDidLoad method above is from a viewController using your custom view?

Comment: Hi Gil, I see you are new here.  If you ask a question and the answer is helpful you can click and accept the answer, you all get a couple reputation points for that and it is a nice thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.nameView.newName resignFirstResponder];
```

is the same as:

```
[[[self nameView] newName] resignFirstResponder];
```

which means that newName is a method and methods that begin with `new` or `copy` are expected to return a retained instance.  I suspect that newName does not do that but the rules say it does.  The solution is to follow Objective-C naming rules: change the name `newName`.

Not, you don't say but perhaps newName is a property.  Well, @synthesize creates accessor methods `newName` and `setNetName`.

Comment: Thanks CocoaFu - the renaming did it.